# Defining named parameters for a customized NN module in Pytorch

Tags: parameters, module, neural-network, pytorch, customization

This question is about how to appropriately define the parameters of a customized layer in Pytorch.  I am wondering how one can make the parameter to end up being **named parameter**?

```
class My_layer(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mu = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.0],[1.0]]))
```

So that when I print the parameters as below, the p.name is not empty.

```
my_layer = My_Layer()
for p in my_layer.parameters():
     print(p.name, p.data, p.requires_grad)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are registering your parameter properly, but you should use [`nn.Module.named_parameters`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.named_parameters) rather than `nn.Module.parameters` to access the names. Currently you are attempting to access `Parameter.name`, which is probably not what you want. The `name` attribute of `Parameter` and `Tensor` do not appear to be documented, but as far as I can tell, they refer to an internal attribute of the `_C._TensorBase` class and cannot be modified externally.

Every time you assign a `Parameter` to an attribute of your module it is registered with a name (this occurs in `nn.Module.__setattr__` [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/789e9353044eb2227462ef470e4b362ac025be4d/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L813)). The parameter always takes the same name as the attribute itself, so `"mu"` in this case. To iterate over all the parameters and their associated names use `nn.Module.named_parameters`. For example,

```py
my_layer = My_Layer()
for n, p in my_layer.named_parameters():
    print('Parameter name:', n)
    print(p.data)
    print('requires_grad:', p.requires_grad)
```

which prints

```
Parameter name: mu
tensor([[0.],
        [1.]])
requires_grad: True
```

Comment: What part is the registering part?  Should I use self.mu = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.0],[1.0]]))  or   self.mu = torch.nn.named_parameter(torch.tensor([[0.0],[1.0]]))  when defining the param?

Comment: `self.mu = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.tensor([[0.0],[1.0]]))` registers the parameter named `"mu"`. This happens behind the scenes (in your Module's __setattr__ method). Your initial method for registering parameters was correct, but to get the name of the parameters when you iterate over them you need to use `Module.named_parameters()` instead of `Module.parameters()` as demonstrated in this answer.

Comment: How come Module.named_parameters() does not return a subset of what Module.parameters() returns?! I mean, how come such a counter-intuitive terminology made sense enough to be used in naming Pytorch classes?

Comment: I can't say why the designers of the API named the methods in the way that they did. It's unfortunate that the name is ambiguous. I agree that it seems like "named_parameters" implies some parameters aren't named, but its actually returning the same as "parameters" but simply returns their names as well (as indicated in the documentation).